# Dao that retrieves two sets of data

Tags: java, dao

Lets say we have an application that processes Vehicles that are in the Vehicles database table.

All processing logic is identical and can be used to process Sedans and Trucks.

There is a critical point where the application will request from the DAO Vehicles, depending on the process it might need Sedans or Trucks (not both).

What would be a good approach to handle this?

Have in mind the following:

1. Send a parameter to the DAO method saying which type of data we need.
2. Set the DAO to a "mode" to focus on a specific set of data.
3. Have two DAO implementations for each set of Data. Perhaps have a Abstract DAO and two implementations. And the service/controller can use the necessary DAO.

Can anyone recommend a solution or comment and recommend any of the above?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the dao can be used by different calls in a multithreading environment don't use a "mode". It could results in invalid calls. Consider the following steps:

```
Thread 1 set dao mode to truck
Thread 2 set dao mode to sedan
Thread 1 read data. It reads sedans instead of trucks
```

The solution with one additional parameter (type) seams a good one, extracting trucks (or sedans) can be part of the request.

Note that this solution is not the best one if in future it is possible to have additionals vehicles. It breaks the Open Closed Principle.
Here a brief description of OCP from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)):

> software entities … should be open for extension, but closed for
>   modification.

So the best approach to this situation is to have a dao interface and two different dao implementations one for sedans and one for trucks. If an additional vehicle will exists in the future no modification to existing code is needed but is necessary to write only a new class implementing the dao interface. This guarantees the Open Closed Principle.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Open Closed Principle is very important.